# Palavras cujo singular é igual ao plural: Lápis, vírus, etc

Tags: ortografia

Sabemos que é assim, e até há regras para isolar essas palavras com forma única tanto no plural quanto no singular.

Mas por que é assim? Por que não há no português uma regra para formar plural com essas palavras?

Exemplos: Vírus, lápis, ônibus, atlas, ...

Comment: Regra há. As palavras que terminam em -s só são marcadas com *-es* no caso de serem acentuadas na última sílaba. Caso contrário, não mudam para a forma plural.

Comment: Sim regra há, a dúvida é por que a regra é assim, e não similar ao espanhol ou inglês: es=eses, us=uses, is=ises, etc. Não deve ser para causar sentido dúbio propositalmente. Estética fonética? Enfim, deve ter um motivo de ainda ser​ mantido assim, em todos os países falantes de pt.

Comment: a formação do plural em castelhano para as palavras que terminam em *-s* é exatamente como o português: el/los campus, la/las dosis, mas el autobús/los autobuses, cortés/corteses. O asturiano segue essa regra, e imagino o galego e mirandês (e tal vez aragonês e catalão) seguem-na também.

Answer (score 3):

Conforme respondido por @guifa em um comentário, existe regra sim.

> Os substantivos terminados em "s" formam o plural com o acréscimo de "es", apenas quando são oxítonos (acentuados na última sílaba). Vocábulos paroxítonos ou proparoxítonos, tem o plural expresso pelo artigo, pronome ou numeral que os precedem, pelo adjetivo ou verbo que a eles se referem, ou então pelo contexto.
>
> exemplos de substantivos "não oxítonos" terminando em "s" e seus plurais:
>
> - **lápis** - os lápis, város lápis, cinco lápis, lápis pretos.
> - **bônus** - os bônus recebidos.
> - **óculos** - meus óculos, os óculos, óculos escuros ("óculos", como órtese ou objeto de adorno, já é um substantivo no plural. Ninguém diz **meu óculo** ou **meu óculos**. Nesse caso a língua portuguesa funciona da mesma forma que a língua inglesa, i.e, "my glasses are...")
> - **pires** - dois pires, vários pires, pires quebrados.
> - **ônibus** - vários ônibus estacionados. ("parqueados" ou "aparcados" em pt-PT)

Comment: Em pt-PT preferimos "estacionado" a "aparcado", e acho que não usamos "parqueado". (Já agora, cá, um ônibus é um autocarro ou uma camioneta.)

Comment: @ANeves    Camioneta seria um ônibus de dimensões convencionais ou um ônibus pequeno?   Em pt-BR temos a "camionete" que é um tipo de van.

Comment: Têm ambos o mesmo tamanho, mais coisa menos coisa. Levam 30-50 pessoas. Um autocarro é um veículo de transporte público de passageiros urbano, e uma camioneta (também chamada de "carreira" em alguns lugares) é um veículo de transporte público de passageiros rural, interurbano, ou de longo curso. Têm configurações ligeiramente diferentes, porque num viaja-se mais de pé e o outro é de mais longo curso. Mas fora isso, poderiam ser semelhantes.

Comment: Uma camioneta, ou camionete, pode também ser um veículo de transporte de materiais. Não confundir com carrinha, que é outro tipo de veículo transporte de materiais! Nem com furgão (e.g. Toyota Hyace)... bolas, acho que isto dava para escrever uma tese de mestrado.

Comment: pt-BR nem sempre o nome usado pelas pessoas no dia-a-dia é o mesmo que a legislação confere. Camioneta (tipo misto) leva carga e passageiros em compartimentos não separados. Camioneteleva leva carga e passageiros em compartimentos separados. Furgão é um veículo de carga. Furgões podem ser transformados em Micro-ônibus colocando bancos conforme legislação conhecidos por VAN. Microônibus são ônibus leves. E ônibus existem os rodoviários (poltronas) e os urbanos (bancos estofados - as pessoas podem ir em pé). etc

Comment: @AndréLyra  Mas o Brasil é um país enorme, e os nomes de veículos não são padronizados e, se são, ninguém conhece essa padronização.  E existem apelidos para os diversos tipos de carro.  Eu mesmo desconheço alguns e sei mais ou menos do que se trata mas não sei o que define perfeitamente determinados veículos agrícolas e de carga.  E veja também, em algumas regiões, diz-se "podem ir em pé dentro do ônibus".  Já em outras é "podem ir de pé..."   É o Brasil, país continente.